# Do I need separate Struts Action for each form?

Tags: validation, struts2

Do I need separate Struts action for each form?

Currently, one web page have two forms in jsp.  I currently put all validation code in `validate()` in the Action class.  The problem is that it appears the net result is that Form A will then be linked to Form B and vice versa since the validation code is inside the same Action class.

So am I correct that if I want the two forms to be validated independently, then I would require two separate Actions?

Comment: You can do something Like this,try having xml validation in which both form A and form B fields should be included...with the same action...

Answer (score 1):

Form A:

```xml
<font color="red" size="2"><s:actionerror /> <s:fielderror /></font>
<s:form action="NewcreateUser" method="post">
    <s:textfield  type="text" name="form1filed" key="temp" size="11" label="Mobile_Num" required="true"></s:textfield><br />
    <s:submit value="Continue" id="continueSignUp" validate="true"></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

Form B:

```xml
<font color="red" size="2"><s:actionerror /> <s:fielderror /></font>
<s:form action="NewcreateUser" method="post">
    <s:textfield  type="text" name="form2filed" key="formb" size="11" label="Mobile_Num" required="true"></s:textfield><br />
    <s:submit value="Continue" id="continueSignUp" validate="true"></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

Here You can validate your fields,both  form1filed,form2filed with the same Action class

NewcreateUser,And the NewcreateUser-validation.xml file looks like this,

```xml
<field name="form1filed"> 
    <field-validator type="required" short-circuit="true">
        <message key="form1filed Is Required" />
    </field-validator>
</field>

<field name="form2filed"> 
    <field-validator type="required" short-circuit="true">
        <message key="form2filed Is Required" />
    </field-validator>
</field>
```